# doccano labeling on the fly without using the predefined labels set

Tags: annotations, label, doccano

Does Doccano supports labeling on the fly without actually defining a predefined set of labels to annotate the documents?
I need to annotate documents and create new labels other than the predefined ones on the fly.
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately, you cannot Annotate any text without Defining a set of labels/Entities.** If you have a set of labels in JSON format, you can upload them, which is a handy feature.
[image: demo]

check their documentation for more: [Doccano](https://doccano.github.io/doccano/tutorial/#define-labels)